# Flutter : FCM foreground method doesn't work for IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to display a custom DialogBox when receiving a notification with the app in foreground state. The DialogBox should be opened by calling the PushNotificationSystem.readUserRideRequestInformation method and passing rideRequestId contained within the "data" field.

This is the Dart code:

```
    /// when app is open and notification came then this will be called
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {

      notificationData=message?.data;
      RemoteNotification? notification = message!.notification;

      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
         PushNotificationSystem.readUserRideRequestInformation(message.data['rideRequestId'], navigatorKey.currentState!.context);
         
      }
    });
```

This is sender code :

```
Map bodyNotification =
    {
      "body":"TEST",
      "title":"Test",
      "sound":"default",
      "timeToLive": 86400,
      "priority":"high",
      "importance":"high",
      "android_channel_id": "high_importance_channel_2"
    };

    Map dataMap =
    {
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "id": "1",
      "status": "done",
      "rideRequestId": userRideRequestId
    };

    Map officialNotificationFormat =
    {
      "to": deviceRegistrationToken,
      "notification": bodyNotification,
      "priority": "high",
      "data": dataMap,
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
 /// when app is open and notification came then this will be called
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {

  notificationData=message?.data;
  RemoteNotification? notification = message!.notification;

  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
     PushNotificationSystem.readUserRideRequestInformation(message.data['rideRequestId'], navigatorKey.currentState!.context);
     
  }
});
```

with

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {

  notificationData=message?.data;
  RemoteNotification? notification = message!.notification;
  if (notification != null) {
     PushNotificationSystem.readUserRideRequestInformation(message.data['rideRequestId'], navigatorKey.currentState!.context);

  }
});
```